# how to use mongodb with Next js ISR / SSR google cloud function (firebase) | incremental static regeneration firebase nextjs

Tags: mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js

Does anybody here know how to use mongodb when using Next.js and Google cloud function? I tried the example and it works, but when I try using `src` folder that contains server folder (for cloud function) and client folder (app folder) it does not work and browser say: `Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns' mongodb..`

I put the code under `src/client` folder

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

const { MONGODB_URI, MONGODB_DB } = process.env

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error(
    'Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local'
  )
}

if (!MONGODB_DB) {
  throw new Error(
    'Please define the MONGODB_DB environment variable inside .env.local'
  )
}

/**
 * Global is used here to maintain a cached connection across hot reloads
 * in development. This prevents connections growing exponentially
 * during API Route usage.
 */
let cached = global.mongo

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongo = { conn: null, promise: null }
}

export async function connectToDatabase() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }

    cached.promise = MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((client) => {
      return {
        client,
        db: client.db(MONGODB_DB),
      }
    })
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise
  return cached.conn
}
```

Comment: You mentioned you tried an example and it worked. What example is that?

Comment: @juliomalves Probably one of [these](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples), specificity would help. But this isn't a gcloud function error, this is an npm error, npm can't find "mongodb". You can find more information about installing mongodb for Next.js [here](https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/nextjs-with-mongodb/)

Comment: Could you add a bit more information regarding your issue? J. Malves wanted to know what example you were trying, and I would like to know whether you've changed the route to "mongodb" module, as that's what npm is complaining about (the error you're getting isn't from the browser, it's from npm, the browser is just relaying the message). Let us know if this issue is solved or if it persists @Super Noob